# Query for missing fields in nested documents

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I have a user document which contains many tags 
Here is the mapping:

```
{
  "user" : {
    "properties" : {
      "tags" : {
        "type" : "nested",
        "properties" : {
          "id" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed",
            "store" : "yes"
          },
          "current" : {
            "type" : "boolean"
          },
          "type" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "value" : {
            "type" : "multi_field",
            "fields" : {
              "value" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "analyzer" : "name_analyzer"
              },
              "value_untouched" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed",
                "include_in_all" : false
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here are the sample user documents: 
User 1

```
{
  "created_at": 1317484762000,
  "updated_at": 1367040856000,
  "tags": [
    {
      "type": "college",
      "value": "Dhirubhai Ambani Institute of Information and Communication Technology",
      "id": "a6f51ef8b34eb8f24d1c5be5e4ff509e2a361829"
    },
    {
      "type": "company",
      "value": "alma connect",
      "id": "58ad4afcc8415216ea451339aaecf311ed40e132"
    },
    {
      "type": "company",
      "value": "Google",
      "id": "93bc8199c5fe7adfd181d59e7182c73fec74eab5",
      "current": true
    },
    {
      "type": "discipline",
      "value": "B.Tech.",
      "id": "a7706af7f1477cbb1ac0ceb0e8531de8da4ef1eb",
      "institute_id": "4fb424a5addf32296f00013a"
    },    
  ]
}
```

User 2:

```
{
  "created_at": 1318513355000,
  "updated_at": 1364888695000,
  "tags": [
    {
      "type": "college",
      "value": "Dhirubhai Ambani Institute of Information and Communication Technology",
      "id": "a6f51ef8b34eb8f24d1c5be5e4ff509e2a361829"
    },
    {
      "type": "college",
      "value": "Bharatiya Vidya Bhavan's Public School, Jubilee hills, Hyderabad",
      "id": "d20730345465a974dc61f2132eb72b04e2f5330c"
    },
    {
      "type": "company",
      "value": "Alma Connect",
      "id": "93bc8199c5fe7adfd181d59e7182c73fec74eab5"
    },
    {
      "type": "sector",
      "value": "Website and Software Development",
      "id": "dc387d78fc99ab43e6ae2b83562c85cf3503a8a4"
    }    
  ]
}
```

User 3:

```
{
  "created_at": 1318513355001,
  "updated_at": 1364888695010,
  "tags": [
    {
      "type": "college",
      "value": "Dhirubhai Ambani Institute of Information and Communication Technology",
      "id": "a6f51ef8b34eb8f24d1c5be5e4ff509e2a361821"
    },
    {
      "type": "sector",
      "value": "Website and Software Development",
      "id": "dc387d78fc99ab43e6ae2b83562c85cf3503a8a1"
    }    
  ]
}
```

Using the above ES documents for search, I want to construct a query where I need to fetch users who have company tags in nested tag documents or the users who do not have any company tags. What will be my search query?

For example in above case, if search for google tag, then the returned documents should be 'user 1' and 'user 3' (as user 1 has company tag google and user 3 has no company tag). User 2 is not returned as it has a company tag other than google too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not trivial at all, mainly due to the not have a type:company tag clause. Here's what I came up with:

```
{
  "or" : {
    "filters" : [ {
      "nested" : {
        "filter" : {
          "and" : {
            "filters" : [ {
              "term" : {
                "tags.value" : "google"
              }
            }, {
              "term" : {
                "tags.type" : "company"
              }
            } ]
          }
        },
        "path" : "tags"
      }
    }, {
      "not" : {
        "filter" : {
          "nested" : {
            "filter" : {
              "term" : {
                "tags.type" : "company"
              }
            },
            "path" : "tags"
          }
        }
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

It contains an [or filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/or-filter/) with two nested clauses: the first one finds the documents that have tags.type:company and tags.value:google, while the second one finds all the documents that don't have any tags.type:company.

This needs to be optimized though since and/or/not filters don't take advantage of caching for filters that work with bitsets, like the [term filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/term-filter/) does. It would be best to take some more time to find a way to use a [bool filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/bool-filter/) and obtain the same result. Have a lookt [this article](http://euphonious-intuition.com/2013/05/all-about-elasticsearch-filter-bitsets/) to know more.